# other uses of soft core in fpga applications?

Tags: fpga

I recently got a job dealing with FPGAs. My first project is to modify an old board that uses an FPGA + MCU + Flash setup into something like FPGA (with soft core) + Flash, so we'll have one less component to deal with.

I was told the purpose of the MCU in the old board was to program the FPGA on startup (configuration data is saved on the flash). So in my new project, I just have to do exactly the same thing, except no more MCU. Other than this kind of application, what are the other applications of soft core in FPGAs?

Comment: Other than all the other purposes of a MCU?

Comment: well, you could use a dedicated MCU for that, I guess? What I mean is in MCU + FPGA set up

Comment: You would have a MCU that can access all the resources of the FPGA. Such as having 200+ GPIOs. Or 200+ PWM channels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most useful thing about using a soft core CPU is the fact that it's customisable.

Most microcontroller chips come with a set number of on-board peripherals: I2C, SPI, GPIO, PWM channels are all limited to however many they give you.

In a soft core processor, if you need 10 I2C channels and nothing else, then you can design your soft core to do only that. This dedicates resources only to what you want to do and nothing else.

Additionally, when the microcontroller is soft core, it can be removed with a re-flash of the FPGA. An conventional on-board microcontroller would take significantly more effort to remove from the design. This means that optimisation of the FPGA firmware or revising the board for a different purpose would allow for easy removal of the soft core for applications where it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 3):

If the ONLY purpose of the MCU on the old design was to load the FPGA, then on the new design, you're going to be using one of the self-configuration methods for the FPGA, and you won't need an MCU at all (soft or otherwise).

But if the MCU was doing anything else at all, then your soft-core CPU will be doing those other things. It just won't be loading the FPGA any more. (If you think about it for 2 seconds, you'll realize that a soft-core CPU *inside* the FPGA *can't* load the FPGA!)

You'll have to examine the source code for the old MCU in order to figure out everything it might have been doing.

Comment: On some FPGAs that allow partial configuration you can auto configure part of the FPGA from an attached SPI Flash chip. Then that initial portion can, using an embedded controller, can load additional data to configure more of the FPGA. This latter configuration could be a smart selection based upon some external determination of what personality that the FPGA is supposed to present.

Comment: I'm not sure if the FPGA we're using can do self-configuration (it's spartan 6). I think it's exactly what Michael was saying (using SPI flash).

Comment: @dringx Spartan6's can do self-configuration using a range of external non-volatile memory devices. You need to download all the technical references for the Spartan6 from the Xilinx website, particularly UG380, the configuration guide.